# Live Trace Enable/Disable NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

I am using NLog for production tracing of a large application. I am looking for a simple add in that allows me to remotely enable/disable various loggers / change their severity at the source during run time.

Are there any easy addins to do this? Do other frameworks support such things?

Update: To be clear, I am starting with logging turned off at startup, but would like to use my log viewer to remotely tell my application to begin sending trace information for particular loggers to log events of severity X or higher. Obviously I can write this myself, just looking for any libraries / logging frameworks that may have this built in.

Comment: What do you mean "change their severity at the source"?  You can modify the logging settings in the app.config, web.config, or NLog.config file to change the level of your loggers.  So, you could start with logging turned off and then, while your app is running, you could turn on logging (and/or change level) for one or more loggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Severity of log messages cannot be changed dynamic. The idea in NLog is not to change the severity of a message, but the routing of those messages.

If you enabled [configuration auto-reload](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#automatic-reconfiguration), you could turn off writing the trace messages, and enabled it when you need with (without application restart)